# generating glyph chart for opentype fonts

Tags: fonts

I have in the past used software to generate nicely formatted PDF charts of all the glyphs in an OTF font.  But I've now forgotten what software that was.  Probably open source.  Can anyone help?

pdfinfo tells me that the charts are generated by cairo 1.8.8.

Comment: Possibly Google Font tools https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools or https://harfbuzz.github.io/utilities.html#utilities-command-line-hbview . Possibly a different tools, but I would bet that it would indirectly use one of such tools I just linked (not uncommon to have fonttools to get the data (all glyphs) in a font file).

Comment: Great that you worked this out, but your answer would be greatly improved and useful to others with a similar problem, if you can explain how you came to your conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was [`fntsample`](https://github.com/eugmes/fntsample). (Personal communication from Mark Penninga)